# How to use OpenNI / NITE in xcode?

Tags: xcode, openni

I have installed OpenNI and NITE on my mac osx.

I want to develop some Kinect apps using XCode(3.2.5 currently I used). 
But after search on web and stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any good resources on how to import those library into an XCode project.

I saw someone use OSCeleton as protocol messager, 
but I would prefer more native way to do that(use OpenNI directly).

Can anyone give me some brief hint about how to do that? 
Even a link is really helpful (sample compilable xcode proj would be great!). 
Apologize if this topic exists before.

Comment: Maybe, this link can help:
[http://davidbliss.com/getting-up-and-running-with-openni-and-nite-o](http://davidbliss.com/getting-up-and-running-with-openni-and-nite-o)

Comment: I think it is where you may see updates to Xcode4. <http://cicconet.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/openni-and-xcode-4/>

Comment: It happens I still use XCode 3.2.6 (on osx 10.6.8) and I've managed to compile one of the samples. After creating a C++ Command Line Tool I needed to setup the header and library search path to point to OpenNI and NITE then add the OpenGL and GLUT frameworks. Also I had to ammend the sample path (to `/private/etc/openni/SamplesConfig.xml` or where OpenNI installs the samples on your machine)

Comment: I've upload one of the samples setup for XCode [here](http://lifesine.eu/so/NiHandTracker.zip). Jcdmb's link is pretty handy. Also, OpenFrameworks+ofxOpenNI makes it easy to develop applications using Kinect/OpenNI. Check the the zip from the [FutureTheatre Workshop Wiki](http://futuretheater.net/wiki/Kinect_Workshop#Kinect_.2B_OpenFrameworks_Workshop) as it ships with ofxOpenNI setup and some neat samples.